# Issues with parametrization of JDBC request with jmeter

Tags: sql, csv, jdbc, jmeter, parameter-passing

I would like to use a predefined queries from csv file.
The problem is that some of the values into the queries must be randomly chosen and each query has different number of parameters.
So i have tried something like this:

"select * from table where column = "${variable1};"
Please note that variable1 is  already defined  and has proper value.

The problem is that jMeter executes the query without replacing the parameter with its value.

It is not an option to use "?" ( question mark) as it is explained into the basic tutorial.

Has anybody has an idea how to solve this issue, without writing custom code using PreSampler like Beanshell, etc.

Comment: possible error `"${variable1};"`  should be `"${variable1}";`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use JMeter variables in SELECT statements

[image: JMeter variable in SQL]

The reasons for not getting it resolved can be

1. (Most likely) Variable is not set. Use [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) to double check its value.
2. You have syntax error in your SQL query
3. If you have a "complex" variable like `variable` - is a prefix and `1` is a random number which comes from i.e. [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) or [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function you need to refer the variable a little bit differently, like:

   - `${__evalVar(variable${__threadNum})}`

   or

   - `${__evalVar(${variable}${__Random(1,9,)})}`

Comment: It seems that i haven't explained my issue properly.
I am taking the whole sql from CSV data set.
So my JDBC sampler is containing only ${query}, where the query value is the whole SQL statement.
And here is the tricky part: Inside the SQL i have several variables "variable1", variable2, etc.
Since i have lots of different SQLs with different parameters and parameters type, I cannot use "?" in the statements.
But although I have provided values for all of the variables, jMeter executes them as explained above. 

The error in the SQL above is typing error, it was just an example.

Comment: Actually Dimitri T, you have answered my question indirectly.
${__evalVar(query)} solves my issue and replace all variable into the query as expected.
Thank you very much!